# MVVMCross Release build not working (LinkerPleaseInclude Listview)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, linker, mvvmcross

When i'm building in debug mode all works fine. When building in Release my MvxListView does not get populated.

This has something to do with the linker and MvvmCross doing reflection magic so the linker can't know where to link the bind to.

They said there is a file called "LinkerPleaseInclude.cs" to help fake the bind as its referenced then.

Somehow my listview still doesn't get populated.. please help me out...

Linkerpleaseinclude file:

```
class LinkerPleaseInclude
{
    public void Include(ICommand command)
    {
        command.CanExecuteChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (command.CanExecute(null))
            {
                command.Execute(null);
            }
        };
    }

    public void Include(MvxListView listview)
    {
        listview.ItemsSource = new List<int>();
        var itemsSource = listview.ItemsSource;
    }

    public void Include(AnimalSearchViewModel viewmodel)
    {
        viewmodel.FilteredAnimals = new List<AnimalListInfoViewModel>();
    }
}
```

AnimalSearchViewModel

```
public class AnimalSearchViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string searchString;
    private MvxCommand<AnimalListInfoViewModel> itemSelectedCommand;

    private readonly IUserDialogs userDialogs;
    private readonly IAnimalsStorage animalsStorage;
    private readonly IMapper mapper;
    private readonly IDebug logger;

    public IEnumerable<Animal> Animals { get; set; }
    public IList<AnimalListInfoViewModel> FilteredAnimals { get; set; }

    public string SearchString
    {
        get
        {
            return this.searchString;
        }
        set
        {
            this.FindResults(value);
        }
    }

    public IMvxCommand ItemSelectedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            this.itemSelectedCommand = this.itemSelectedCommand ?? new MvxCommand<AnimalListInfoViewModel>(this.DoSelectItem);
            return this.itemSelectedCommand;
        }
    }

    public AnimalSearchViewModel(
        IMvxMessenger messenger,
        IUserDialogs dialogs,
        IAnimalsStorage animalsStorage,
        IMapper mapper,
        IDebug logger)
        : base(messenger, "Dierkaart")
    {
        this.userDialogs = dialogs;
        this.animalsStorage = animalsStorage;
        this.mapper = mapper;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public void DoSelectItem(AnimalListInfoViewModel item)
    {
        this.ShowViewModel<AnimalListInfoViewModel>(new { id = item.Id });
        this.logger.LogInfo(DebugTag.Core, "Key: " + item.Key + " Value: " + item);
    }

    protected override async void InitFromBundle(IMvxBundle parameters)
    {
        this.Animals = await this.animalsStorage.GetAnimalsAsync();

        base.InitFromBundle(parameters);
    }

    private void FindResults(string keyword)
    {
        this.searchString = keyword;
        if (this.searchString.Length >= 3)
        {
            var filteredAnimals = this.Animals.Where(i =>
                                                     {
                                                         // TODO: Get real displayvalue
                                                         var displayValue = i.Key;
                                                         return displayValue.IndexOf(this.searchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1;
                                                     }).ToArray();

            this.FilteredAnimals = this.mapper.Map<List<AnimalListInfoViewModel>>(filteredAnimals);
        }
        else
        {
            this.FilteredAnimals = new List<AnimalListInfoViewModel>();
        }
    }
}
```

layoutfile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/search"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="@dimen/md_list_single_line_with_avatar_item_height"
      android:paddingLeft="@dimen/md_list_item_horizontal_edges_padding"
      android:paddingRight="@dimen/md_list_item_horizontal_edges_padding"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
      android:inputType="number"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:hint="Type om te zoeken..." 
      local:MvxBind="Text SearchString"/>
  <Mvx.MvxListView
      android:id="@+id/select_list"
      android:scrollbars="vertical"
      android:layout_below="@id/search"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      local:MvxBind="ItemsSource FilteredAnimals; ItemClick ItemSelectedCommand"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I'd imagine the ItemsSource FilteredAnimals will be filled but that's not working in release mode.. please help me out.

Comment: Are you using `Sdk Assemblies Only` or `Sdk and User Assemblies` option  for linking?

Comment: @Plac3Hold3r SDK Assemblies Only :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the issue is not directly related to your `MvxListView` but rather the text change in your `EditText`. If the value entered is not return to your ViewModel it will not trigger the `FindResult(string keyword)` and update your list `FilteredAnimals`.

You can add `AfterTextChanged` event to your `LinkerPleaseInclude` to prevent the linker from stripping it out.

```
public class LinkerPleaseInclude
{
    public void Include(TextView text)
    {
        text.AfterTextChanged += (sender, args) => text.Text = "" + text.Text;
        text.Hint = "" + text.Hint;
    }
}
```

Comment: This was the key to success! Yet i'm still wondering.. I'm using an EditText as search bar.. Why would i use an include to Textview?

Comment: @Baklap4, you could also use a `EditText`. It is only because an `EditText` inherits and a `TextView`, so linking on lowest base class will guarantee the property/event not being linked out for all inherited classes.

Comment: Thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your code in `LinkerPleaseInclude` is only generating a reference to the `set` accessor of the `ItemsSource` property. You need a reference to the `get` too to avoid it being linked out.

Try this:

```
public void Include(MvxListView listview)
{
    listview.ItemsSource = new List<int>();
    var itemsSource = listView.ItemsSource;
}
```